# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy haciendo una app de un curso en kotlin y no entiendo el código de error haber si alguien me puede ayudar el error me aparece desde que intento implementar un Recycler View Adapter

codigo de error(pongo solo una parte porque si no no me deja publicar):

```
2020-08-11 20:28:53.260 11705-11705/com.english.gameofthrones E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.english.gameofthrones, PID: 11705
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.english.gameofthrones/com.english.gameofthrones.CharactersActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{7136762 VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f070050 app:id/list}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.english.gameofthrones.CharactersActivity@5431e52
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{7136762 VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f070050 app:id/list}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.english.gameofthrones.CharactersActivity@5431e52
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{7136762 VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f070050 app:id/list}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.english.gameofthrones.CharactersActivity@5431e52
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.generateLayoutParams(RecyclerView.java:4304)
```

muchas gracias de antemano:)

Comment: Agrega CharactersActivity y el layout que carga por favor.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge me ha sido útil